# Setting wm_state in python xlib

Tags: x11, python

I want to write my own status bar. I figured it has to have a specific `_NET_WM_STATE` property set to `_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE` (polybar does it). What I can not figure out though is how do I go about it with `python-xlib`. The documentation doesn't explain exactly how to use `set_wm_state` and I thought maybe someone here knows. If there's a better way to let X know my program is supposed to be a bar then also let me know